# Discrete Maths - Range of function

Tags: functions

I'm currently studying CS, and as i didn't do maths A level i'm finding the module particularly difficult. We've now changed topics and lecturer, going onto discrete maths; and i'm refusing to fall behind :P. So, i'm going to post regularly/daily questions, just to make sure i have an understanding.

Hopefully some of you guys have the time to give detailed answers to give me some sort of foundation

Question - Range of a Functon

Let $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $Y = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(a) =1$, $f(b) =2$, $f(c) = 5$, $f(d) = 2$.

Find the domain, codomain and range. If someone could explain this question in detail so i can do some revision on it, i'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: If you’re going to be posting a lot, you should definitely read [this introduction](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typing mathematical symbols here.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the *domain* of $f$ is the set of all inputs for which $f$ is defined; in this case that’s $\{a,b,c,d\}=X$. This is actually implicit in the notation $f:X\to Y$, which almost always implies that that the domain of $f$ is $X$. (I say *almost* because in some areas of mathematics one deals with so-called partial functions from $X$ to $Y$, whose domains may not be all of $X$. I would not worry about this: it should not come up in what you’re doing.)

The codomain can also be read straight from the notation $f:X\to Y$: it’s the target set $Y$, which here is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The range is always a subset of the codomain: it’s the set of values that the function actually assumes (or if you prefer — and in CS you might! — outputs). For your function $f$ those values are $1,2$, and $5$, so the range of $f$ is the set $\{1,2,5\}$.

That’s all there is to it.

Comment: Actually partial functions come up quite often in fundamental computer science (such as computability theory), though perhaps not in the introductory discrete math courses.

Comment: @Henning: I know, but I doubt that they’ll come up in this course: this sounds like a module on very elementary discrete math topics.

Comment: Hi Brian, Cheers for your Answer. Could you please elaborate on how you gathered the answer for the Range. I don't know whether it's because i'm tired or just stupid :P Not really understanding why you chose them three numbers in particular out of the 5. Thanks!

Comment: @harry: Those are the only outputs of the function: $1$ is $f(a)$, $2$ is $f(b)$ and $f(d)$, and $5$ is $f(c)$. There is no element of $X$ that $f$ sends to $3$ or to $4$, so $3$ and $4$ aren’t in the range of $f$, though they are in $f$’s codomain $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Domain** is a set on which valid inputs to $f$ are defined. Since $f$ is defined on $a,b,c,d$, the domain is the entire $X$.

**Range** is a set to which $f$ maps the input -- in other words, all possible outputs of $f$. Here, $\{1,2,5\}$. Sometimes range is called **image**.

**Codomain** is the bigger set where every output must be defined, here it is $Y$

For another example consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 1/x^2$.

- The domain are all possible inputs, so $0$ is not a part of it since $1/0$ is undefined. So the domain are all non-zero reals.
- The codomain is where $f$ maps, here is defined as $\mathbb{R}$.
- The image or range of $f$ is the actual outputs of $f$, here all positive reals.